# How to fix Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

I want to transfer per second of given time but I got
Error: Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract ReceiveEther{

    fallback() external payable {}

    function getBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}

contract SendEther {

    uint balance;
    
    function invest() external payable{
         balance += msg.value;
    }

    function getBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }


    function transferBalance(address payable _to, uint endTime) public payable{
        uint startTime = block.timestamp;
        uint totalSecond = endTime + startTime;

        require(_to != msg.sender, "Can't transfer to ownself");
        require(msg.value <= balance, "Insufficent balance.");
        require(msg.value > 0 , "Amount is zero.");
        require(totalSecond > startTime, "stop time before the start time.");

        uint amount = msg.value;
        uint transferPerSecond = amount/endTime;

        while(startTime <= totalSecond){
            uint timeLeft = totalSecond - block.timestamp;
            if(timeLeft > 0){
                _to.transfer(transferPerSecond);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

literally everything is wrong with your `transferBalance` function. Marking a function `payable` means that it's designed to *receive* ether, not to send it. Your second `require` statement doesnt make any sense (it basically prevents a user to send more ether to the contract than what's already in there (if there's 1eth in the contract and the user tries to send 2 eth it would revert). Your while loop is completely broken (After the first iteration, `timeleft` will be equal to `endTime`, after the 2nd iteration trying to compute `timeleft` will result in an underflow. Btw `startTime` will always be smaller than `totalSecond`, which makes it an infinite loop). Also you can't perform any action automatically like this with solidity (sending 1 eth every second simply won't happen, sending 1 eth every block maybe, but you'd need an off chain script for that, that would call on every block a function that sends 1ETH)